# CronJob did not write to log

Tags: bash, cron

I have created a txt file **foo.cron** in which i have this code:

> 0,15,30,45 * * * * echo "i am here >>&/my_working_directory/cron.log

and registering cronjob with

> cronjob foo.cron

and checking cronjob registered with command

> cronjob -l

But I dont get anything written in cron.log file

Comment: You are missing a double quote after `i am here`

Comment: it was edited when i posted here but my code has double quote after I am here..Sorry for that mistake...But even after that it did not work

Comment: I changed the line with 0,15,30,45 * * * * echo "I am here" >/pwd/cron.log and it worked. Anyway thanks for help @fedorqui

Answer (score 0):

Try putting **echo "i am here" >> /my_working_directory/cron.log** to a separate shell script (foo.sh) and add cronjob as shown below:

Edit cronjob

```
crontab -e
```

Add cronjob to execute every 15 mins

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/script/foo.sh
```